# iPhone iOS4 'phone made' Playlists disappear when connecting to iTunes

Tags: itunes, iphone, playlists

With iOS4 it is possible to make new, named custom playlists directly on the phone.

This works fine for me, expect when I connect the iPhone to any machine (mac or pc) that has iTunes running (even if it's not the paired iTunes for the iPhone.) all the customisations that I've made to playlists, new ones or re-ordered existing ones, are destroyed.

Google can't seem to find results for me due to too much noise about iPhones and Playlists.

Does this happen to everyone or just me. It seems like the edits should sync back. BTW I don't have syncing setup on the iphone, and all music is set to be managed manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Latest iTunes 10.2 / iOS4.3 fixes this issue.

Comment: this is not true... I am on ios 4.3 and i have the newest itunes. when i plug in my phone, auto sync is turned off, but right away my iphone shows sync screen and it erases my playlists without doing a real sync. I still have to hit sync to actually sync. So why does it automatically destroy my playlists??